# Is using an object with identical keys & values in a switch statement bad/pointless code?

Tags: javascript, object, switch-statement

So I've come across some of my old code, which is something like :

```
const valStore = {
  val1: "val1"
  val2: "val2"
  val3: "val3"
}
```

And it then is called like so:

```
switch (val) {
  case "val4":
    function()
  break;
  case "val5":
    coolFunction()
  break;
  case valStore[val]:
    otherFunction(val)
...
```

I don't like that there is an entire object with identical keys & values it seems messy as it's only 5 values in the real version, although a fall-through switch statement doesn't seem much better:

```
switch (val) {
  case "val4":
    function()
    break;
  case "val5":
    coolFunction()
    break;
  case "val1":
  case "val2":
  case "val3":
    otherFunction(val)
...
```

I've considered using sets and an else if, I'm not sure about if I want a replacement or if I'm wasting my time. It just got me thinking.

Comment: yes, this is bad pratice.

Comment: Well, right now `valStore` is just mapping a string to the same string. But that doesn't need to be the case - you could, for example, be mapping multilanguage options, e.g., `valStore = { yes: "yes", ja: "yes", si: "yes", no: "no", nein: "no" }` in which case it can be useful to have this level of indirection.

Comment: @VLAZ you could do the same with nested maps like [Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/sCE1a1Gb)

Comment: @VLAZ or you can do it in an alt way like [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/JN33Wn69)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen neither of the two do what I described. Moreover, the multilingual content was an example where you might want to map multiple inputs to the same output. Also consider 1->true, "yes"->true, "true"->true, ✔->true to convert multiple types of values to the same canonical representation in the system. Consider for example importing data from a file - users can type in one of many valid values which just gets translated to a system value afterwards. Language maps are not appropriate for that case.

Comment: "*a fall-through switch statement doesn't seem much better*" - it absolutely does seem better. No duplication, no weird indirection that's hard to understand, just a straightforward list of cases.

Comment: @Bergi generally building for scale of large data. example, like a game would end up having multiple json files each for said language, like en.json, de.json, etc... for small langs projects then a nested json array would work.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Not sure where you got "language" from, OP's code doesn't look i18n-related to me

Comment: @VLAZ For `switch (val) … case valStore[val]: …` to have an effect, the value must be the same as the key for every property of the object

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the `switch`, you could put the function references in the object and invoke them directly:

```js
const valStore = {
  val1: otherFunction,
  val2: otherFunction,
  val3: otherFunction,
  val4: function() { /* your logic here */ },
  val5: coolFunction
}

valStore[val]();
```

I would also suggest finding a way to remove the `valX: otherFunction` duplication, but without knowing the context and structure of your logic it's difficult to suggest a workable alternative.

Comment: you are missing a default case, so that if an invalid val is passed, then it will throw an error, see my answer

Comment: Good point. I presumed validation was a basic enough concept the OP had it covered already.